Creating pose library thumbnails in Blender 4.2
I'm an animation newbie trying to use the pose library. I can create and reuse poses, but each pose has a generic image that looks like an exclamation mark.Regenerating the image doesn't make any difference. Any suggestions?

I solved it (I think) by making the character appear in the appropriate size in camera view. No color, but at least the pose is there.
